# how to make one ng-repeat to work on different columns in different rows

Tags: html, angularjs, pug

I am trying to display data formulated like this using angular

```
"a":[{
    "name": "a's name"
    "b":[{
        "name":"b's name"
        "c":[{
            "name": "c's name"
            "d":[{
                "name":"d's name"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

and i tried this but it couldn't work

```
tr
    td(ng-repeat="oneB in a.b")
    | {{oneB.name}}
tr
    td(ng-repeat="oneC in oneB.c")
    | {{oneC.name}}
tr
    td(ng-repeat="oneD in oneC.d")
    | {{oneD.name}}
```

and also this

```
tr
    td(ng-repeat-start="oneB in a.b")
    | {{oneB.name}}
tr
    td(ng-repeat-end,ng-repeat-start="oneC in oneB.c")
    | {{oneC.name}}
tr
    td(ng-repeat-end,ng-repeat="oneD in oneC.d")
    | {{oneD.name}}
```

i really need help.

i am currently developing in **MEAN stack** (Mongodb Express.js Angular.js and Node.js) and also **PUG**

[desired Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hChgv.png)

[JSON Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LPoA.png)

Comment: i think your json structure is not the best one for your goals. what is your desired output?

Comment: if you are developing in mean stack and you have control over the services adjust your json object to match a more simple structure

Comment: @firegloves I added the desired output. name:"desired Image"

Comment: it's very difficult to tell how the JSON structure you are showing relates to the table structure you are trying to show in your "desired image".  it's also not clear what "it couldn't work" means, exactly.  It doesn't look to me like this data is organized in a manner that makes the output you are expecting reasonable to accomplish.

Comment: would you advise me on the JSON structure that would give the output i added? thanks

Comment: ok let me take some screenshot of the real JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = [{
    "name": "a's name",
    "b":[{
        "name":"b's name",
        "c":[{
            "name": "c's name",
            "d":[{
                "name":"d's name"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  
  <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
  
    <div ng-repeat="a in data"> 
      {{ a.name }}
      <div ng-repeat="b in a.b">
        {{ b.name }}
        <div ng-repeat="c in b.c">
          {{ c.name }}
          <div ng-repeat="d in c.d">
            {{ d.name }}
          </div> 
        </div> 
      </div>       
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it would work but wouldn't give me the output i want.